# How to hide some rows in a tableview javafx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

How can i hide some rows between two dates just in the tableview ?
i'm trying to show rows that are between 2021-06-12 and 2021-06-14

Comment: Remove the "hidden" items from the underlying `List` used for the `TableView`. You can either do this with "List.remove()` or create a `FilteredList` with an appropriate `predicate`.

Comment: `FilteredList` is almost certainly the correct approach for this.